# How it is possible to differentiate between encrypted and an unencrypted bluetooth traffic

Tags: iphone, encryption, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I captured bluetooth traffic between a **master vault Bluetooth smart padlock** and an **iPhone 6s**. 
This was done using a bluetooth sniffer and the captured traffic was stored to a pcap file. 
Analysing it on wireshark displays all the packets transferred between the two devices and the attributes that were changed during the write process. Obviously there's not much data exchanged between an iphone when it's working with a locking device so I was wondering, **how it is possible to differentiate between encrypted and an unencrypted bluetooth traffic in this case?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to software development. [su] or [security.se] seem much more appropriate for this type of question.

Comment: Sorry, i'll move my question.

Comment: when you say "using a bluetooth sniffer" , is this the air packets or HCI communication between host and controller?, from your description it seems like a Host to Bluetooth controller communication. please clarify, it would be helpful if you mention the sniffer used.

Comment: @bare_metal The sniffer used was the Ubertooth One and it was air packets not HCI communication.